# error message when trying to generate help tags for surround.vim

Tags: vim

When i try to install surround.vim by placing it in the vimfiles folder and i'm not sure whether vimrc needs changing either and i get an error in the editor e149 cannot open file for writing when trying to generate helptags, can anyone please advise?

Comment: Please try to be more specific next time. Where exactly did you install, and what command did you type to generate the helptags? This will make it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on windows?

Your setup is supposed to look like that:

```
%userprofile%\vimfiles\plugin\surround.vim
%userprofile%\vimfiles\doc\surround.txt
```

After you are done, start Vim and issue the following command to add surround's documentation to the general `:help`:

```
:helptags \path\to\vimfiles\doc
```

You can now do `:help surround`.